# Does Sightly really not support any arithmetic operators?

Tags: arithmetic-expressions, sightly

I'm trying to subtract 2 from the total number of items in a list in Sightly.

```
<ul data-sly-list="${javaClass.list}">
    <li>
         <span> ${itemList.size -2 @ context='number'}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The result is:

> org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.SightlyException: Parsing error in
>   template ...: token recognition error at: '-' for expression
>   ${itemList.size -2 @ context='number'}

Do I really have to create a method in Java for this? Like:

```
javaClass.getListCountMinusTwo()
```

I'd be grateful for any kind of workaround.

Comment: BTW `getListCountMinusTwo` is code smell, you should probably have something more meaningful there (as in time you might discover that you will need to offset the count by a different value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sightly only supports logical and comparison operators ([spec](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#114-operators)) and that is intended as the view rendering scripts are not supposed to contain business logic, this should come from the model/use-objects.